# Overloading function with google test

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

In my TestMock class I have two mock methods

1. MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(function1, const bool&());
2. MOCK_METHOD0(function1, bool&());

In the test fixture I want to call the second mock, but my test is calling the first.

```
    EXPECT_CALL(*testMock, function1());
```

What I must to write in EXPECT_CALL for calling second mock?

EXAMPLE:

```
class TestA
{
public:
    virtual ~ TestA() {}
    bool foo1()
    {
        return function1();
    }
    virtual bool& function1() = 0;
    virtual const bool& function1() const = 0;
};


class TestMock : public TestA
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(function1, const bool&());
    MOCK_METHOD0(function1, bool&());
    virtual ~ TestMock () {}

};
class TestConfiguration : public :: testing :: Test
{
    void SetUp()
    {


    }

    void TearDown()
    {
        delete testMock;
    }

public:
TestMock *testMock;
};
TEST_F(TestConfiguration, testFooTEST)
{
    testMock = new TestMock();

    EXPECT_CALL(*testMock, function1());

    testMock->foo1();
}
```

Comment: Do you think this really works correctly for normal C++ code when you don't use mocking?

Comment: Yes, it calls a constant method. I check it via breakpoint

Comment: @АлександрБодров Post a [MCVE] in your question please.

Comment: @АлександрБодров You probably need to ensure that `*Foo` is a `const` instance. You can try `*const_cast<const decltype<Foo>*>(Foo)`.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: [OT]: You don't need `new/delete`, use directly `TestMock testMock;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From CookBook at https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/v1_5/CookBook.md#selecting-between-overloaded-functions

```
TestMock testMock;

EXPECT_CALL(testMock, function1())         // The non-const function1().
    .WillOnce(Return(true));
EXPECT_CALL(Const(testMock), function1())  // The const function1().
    .WillOnce(Return(false));
```